# How can i trigger plupload select dialog after page load automatically?

Tags: plupload

How can I automatically trigger a plupload select dialog after the page loads?
It works fine when we click on a button. I tried with:

```
$('#pickfiles').plupload('start');
$('div.moxie-shim input[type=file]').trigger('click');
```